# count cells in month range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that has cells with dates, at the sheet level the format is "2" but if I click the text it is "01/02/2023 17:12:37".
I have tried using the "countif" function in these ways:

> `=CONTAR.SI(J:J; "???ene.")`
>
> and
>
> `=CONTAR.SI(J:J; "??/01/2023*")`

*The functions are in Spanish*

and it returns 0, am I failing in the format? or that for my problem there is some function that already exists?

> [image: dateCell]
>
> This is the format and display of the cells that contain the date, it
> is an Excel format, it is not a custom one

My version of excel is the one from 2019

Comment: bracket: `=COUNTIFS(J:J,">="&DATE(2023,1,1),J:J,"<"&DATE(2023,2,1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner When I put it in the corresponding cell and press enter and that the inner parentheses are in red, I get the warning that there is a problem with the formula and that if I am trying to enter a formula that if I start with = excel thinks it is a formula that if not use " ' "

Comment: can you post the exact formula you are trying?

Comment: @ScottCraner I copied and pasted yours

Comment: @ScottCraner I have already found the error, I think it was due to the format of the formula for using a comma instead of a semicolon, this is the new formula: `=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(J:J; ">=" & FECHA(2023;1;1); J:J; "<" & FECHA(2023;2;1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner If you want, put the formula with a semicolon in an answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: This is an english site that has defaulted to the EN-US style, my answer would use the `,` as the answer would follow EN-US style.

Comment: A few remarks: "ene" stands for "enero", which means "January" in English. Next just a question: are you aware of the subtotals feature, which you can use for such a thing? (https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/insert-subtotals-in-a-list-of-data-in-a-worksheet-7881d256-b4fa-4f81-b71e-b0a3d4a52b3a)

Comment: @Dominique I didn't know about that function, I'll look to see if it also helps me to have several options, although on the website it appears that they no longer work in Excel tables, anyway, thank you very much for telling me that other option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function

```
=COUNTIFS(J:J,">="&DATE(2023,1,1),J:J,"<"&DATE(2023,2,1))
```

translated into Spanish

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(J:J; ">=" & FECHA(2023;1;1); J:J; "<" & FECHA(2023;2;1))
```